# python stdin with txt file and input() function

Tags: python, input, stdin

I have a input.txt file with the following content.

```
3 
4 5
```

I want to use this as a standard input by using the following command in the command line.

```
python a.py < input.txt
```

In the a.py script, I am trying to read the input line by line using `input()` function. I know there are better ways to read the stdin, but I need to use `input()` function.

A naive approach of

```
line1 = input()
line2 = input()
```

did not work. I get the following error message.

```
File "<string>", line 1
  4 5
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Answer (score 1):

That way is ok, it works:

```
read = input()
print(read)
```

but you are just reading one line.

From the [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) doc:

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string
>   (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

That means that if the file does not end with a blank line, or what is the same, the last nonblank line of the file do not end with an `end of line` character, you will get `exceptions.SyntaxError` and the last line will not be read.

Comment: I added more detail. I get an error when I try to read the second line.

Comment: @hwchung I edited my answer. Any particular reason why you have to stick with the `input()` func? As I see the situation, or you add an end line to the end of your file, or you will have to use another way besides `input()` to read the content of the file that you passed as the standard input of the script. Exist several other options, just let me know if you are interested in them ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to stick with input() function because what I am trying to do is to debug my code used in HackerRank website. There I use input() function to take the input. It is much easier to debug using my local machine. So I am trying to write a code for taking the input locally. What do you mean by adding end line to the end of my file?

Comment: @hwchung iterating over `sys.stdin` is a bit more versatile.

Comment: @hwchung as Nick T said, [sys.stdin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) is a good alternative. You can treat it like any normal file and do things like `for line in sys.stdin:`, `sys.stdin.readlines()` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You mention HackerRank; looking at some of my old submissions, I think I opted to give up on `input` in lieu of `sys.stdin` manipulations. `input()` is very similar to `next(sys.stdin)`, but the latter will handle EOF just fine.

By way of example, my answer for https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximize-it/

```
import sys
import itertools

# next(sys.stdin) is functionally identical to input() here
nK, M = (int(n) for n in next(sys.stdin).split())

# but I can also iterate over it
K = [[int(n) for n in line.split()][1:] for line in sys.stdin]

print(max(sum(x**2 for x in combo) % M for combo in itertools.product(*K)))
```